# Dikduk- yud suffix on a hebrew verb

Tags: grammar-dikduk

In Parshas Bo 10:1 it states  למען שתי the yud here indicates that Hashem is doing the placing.

I was wondering that generally, the yud indicates possessiveness on nouns, however over here it is qualifying a verb, not a noun. There is a similar instance in Parshas "ויצא כט יט "טוב תתי .

I was wondering if there is any rule for when we find a yud suffix indication possessiveness (or more precisely explaining who is doing the action) on verbs.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Yakov and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Thanks  for the question. To give it more substance, could you please quote an example where the yud suffix on a verb indicates possessiveness?

Comment: I don't understand how a verb can have a suffix for possessiveness, can you give an example?

Comment: I think in both cases, the word is acting as a gerund rather than a verb.

Comment: I thought I gave instances Numbers 10:1 and Genesis 29:19

Comment: If you don't mind **my asking**, have you never seen the same phenomenon in English?